# how to evenly set limited number of label matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I have a graph like this ,it records every hours data for 21 days, the labels are like:
01-30 00:00, 01-30 01:00....now they are unreadable, so I want to set only one label per day, so only show everyday's first label: 01-30 00:00, 01-31 00:00,etc

my code is:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()  
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ind = np.arange(len(timelist))
ax.bar(ind,reqlist,color='b')
ax.set_xlim((0,len(timelist)))
ax.set_ylabel('Number of request/video',size='x-large')
ax.set_title('Request per hour North',size='xx-large')
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(timelist,rotation=17)
```

timelist is a list of string: ["01-30 00:00", "01-30 00:01".....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try giving only the labels you want and give an empty string for the rest.
For example if you want only the label every 24 (one day):

```
newlist = []
for index, item in enumerate(timelist):
    if index % 24 == 0:
        newlist.append(item)
    else:
        newlist.append('')
ax.set_xticklabels(newlist, rotation=17)
```